# How can I do better than brute force in finding closest location?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, geolocation, coordinates

I have the following code:

```
public static Location findClosest(Location myPosition, ArrayList<Location> spots) {  
  double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;  
  Location closer = null;  
  for(MyPosition aPosition:spots) {  
     float dist = Math.abs(aPosition.distanceTo(myPosition));  
     if(dist < min) {  
         min = dist;  
         closer = aPosition;  
     }  
  }  
  return closer;  
}
```

This is a brute force O(N^2) approach because this is called from the following function:

```
public static Location findClosest(Location myPosition, ArrayList<Places> places) {   
   Location closer = null;  
   double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;    
   for(Places place:places) {  
      Location currentMin = findClosest(myPosition, places.getSpots());  
      float dist = Math.abs(currentMin.distanceTo(myPosition));  
      if(dist < min) {  
         min = dist;  
         closer = currentMin;  
      }  
   }  
   return closer;  
}
```

which for now works ok taking into account that the size of spots is not that big ~200 max.
What can I do to improve my approach?
Besides geohashing is there any other algorithm I could use for better performance?
Is there some property of coordinates I could use to skip some parts of my loop?

Comment: you could use priority queue instead of the list and you will get O(1) at this point, also I kinda see O(n) here, unless I missed something...

Comment: I cannot see the O(N^2) - but only linear. Anyway, if you are able to "somehow" preprocess spots  you can store them in some spatial data structure such as R-tree, QuadTree, KD-Tree etc... to speed up searching. The right data structure depends on number of dimmensions you use etc.. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: @Palcente:How would the priority queue be used? I didn't understand

Comment: @convexHull:You are right. It is not O(N) because I call this function from another loop which I omitted to mention. I will update OP. I don't know what preprocessing could be

Comment: The order in the priority queue is maintained during insertion. So your `findClosest()` method would just need to pick up the first item from the `spots` and it will be guaranteed it will be the closest location.

Comment: @convexHull:I updated OP. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Palcente:Could you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Because you said O(N^2), but this is a O(N) function, I'll assume you are calling this inside a loop to determine every point's closest. In that case, I don't know what would be faster.

However, to save yourself the trouble of having to run this function each time you want to store a closest point, add a HashMap of all the points to their closest, and check if the point is already added.   If a new point gets added, only check it and all the original points against it.

Hope this helps, if only a little.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to find the nearest "spot" from all the "places" for any location, and your function will be called multiple times (with the same "places" and "spots"), maybe you should consider to create some kind of spatial data structure (that is what I call preprocessing).
For example quad-tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). The construction of the quad-tree may take some time but you will be wery efficient in searching.
- element insertion takes O(log N) (that is totally (N * logN) for N points (your case is probably N = M*M))
- the searching takes only O(log N)
Works perfect with cartesian coordinates. If you are using geographic coordinates you should transform them first.

Comment: My problem is give 1 X location and a list of other locations, find from the list the location nearest to X

Comment: 1) I have the list but the target location is unknown. Can I create such a tree structure to suit this? 2) I have geographic coordinates. What is the best way to convert them?

Comment: If you are searching nearest just for ONCE - these kind of data structures can be overhead and your solution is good enough. but If you searching nearest MULTIPLE times (or if there is a possibility to ask multiple times) you can construct (for example) quad tree for your list of points. Then you can easily ask for any uknown location.
The conversion to cartesian coordinates is not so easy but it is possible.
see for example http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html